# Starting Progress Bar Programmatically

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-progressbar

I want to start a `ProgressBar` programmatically in android. In my activity's UI thread I have the following:

```
ProgressBar progressBar = new progressBar(getApplicationContext(),null,android.R.attr.progressBarStyleLarge);
progressBar.setIndeterminate(true);
progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

but it doesn't appear to be displaying. (I'm instantiating it from `AsyncTask`'s `onPreExecute` method).

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

D'oh! I didn't realise I actually had to add it to the current view of my activity. Told you I was a newbie! ....

```
 progressBar = new ProgressBar(this,null,android.R.attr.progressBarStyleLarge);
 progressBar.setIndeterminate(true);
 progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
 ViewGroup layout = (ViewGroup) findViewById(android.R.id.content).getRootView();
 layout.addView(progressBar);
```

Think that's right :)